# Манипулирование данными при помощи языка SQL

Tags: sql, запрос

Используя оператор «Create table» создать три таблицы:

**Student** – таблица будет содержать информацию о студентах

- Id_st – идентификатор студента
- Surname – ФИО студента

**Exam_st** – таблица будет содержать информацию о экзаменах

- Id_ex – идентификатор экзамена
- Subject – название дисциплины по которой был экзамен
- Date -  дата проведения экзамена

**Mark_st** – таблица будет содержать оценки за экзамен

- Id_ex - идентификатор экзамена
- Id_st - идентификатор студента
- Mark - оценка

Можете объяснить по третьей таблице? Я так понял, нужно первую пару данных брать из других таблиц или создать новые таблицы, так?

```
CREATE TABLE Mark_st (
  Id_ex int = Id_ex from Exam_st
)
```

Comment: Небось они хотят использования FOREIGN KEY

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не знаю.  далее  в задании нужно заполнить таблицы.

Comment: @Showmeyoupower: в вопросе про "далее в задании" ничего не сказано, а на сам вопрос ответ Вам уже дан, нужно использовать внешний ключ.

Comment: @edem а можно пример (как потом брать данные из другой таблицы после использования внешнего ключа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Mark_st (
Id_ex INT,
Id_st INT,
Mark INT,
SmthString VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Id_ex, Id_st)
FOREIGN KEY (Id_ex) REFERENCES Exam_st(Id_ex),
FOREIGN KEY (Id_st) REFERENCES Student(Id_st)
)
```

---

По сути у вас перед заполнением `Mark_st` должны быть заполнены таблицы студентов и экзаменов (словари), чтобы в связывающей таблице можно было сослаться на идентификатор студента/экзамена.

Comment: Извините за такую наглость а можно еще 1 пример добавления в таблицу Марк_ст  (1 строчку хотя бы)

Comment: Я знаю как добавлять свои значения, а как будет добавляться данные из указанных таблиц пока вот не могу сообразить.

Comment: @Showmeyoupower вы хотите понять где "привязываются" таблицы?

Comment: я пропустил пару лекций по ключам  и еще, что то. Вот я не понял если я создам таблицу марк_ст с помощью вашего кода. нужно ли мне потом добавлять данные через Insert into или нет?  Если да то помогите кодом( в виде примера ) и не плохо было бы узнать где привязываются таблицы(сейчас уже гуглю)

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо за помощь. Не понятно почему заминусовали тему? вроде бы может кому то помочь тема.

Comment: @Showmeyoupower, вопрос простой относительно. Но, согласен, кому-то может помочь.